# WebSocket Response Not Showing in Console Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs6

I have implemented RXJS6 Websockets service in angular 8 I am getting the response in Network call but the problem is I am unable to show the response in console or to save the response in any variable.

The webservice code is as follow:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AnonymousSubject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';


@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService {

  constructor() { }

  private subject: Subject<MessageEvent>;
  private connected$ = new Subject<any>();

  public connect(url):Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log("Successfully connected: " + url);
      this.connected$.next(true);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  public connected(): Observable<any> {
    return this.connected$.asObservable();
  }

  private create(url): Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

    let observable = new Observable((obs:  Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

      return ws.close.bind(ws);
  });
    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));

        }
      }
    }
    return Subject.create(observer, observable);


}
}"
```

and in my app.ts file m calling angular connect function it successfully connect to websocket  ad  i start recieving data in my network call but no data shows at console

```
  async connect() {
      this.messages = <Subject<any>>this._websocket
        .connect(this.address).pipe(
        map((response: MessageEvent): any => {

          console.log("response1",response);


          return response.data;
        })) ;


        console.log("websocket",this._websocket);


      this.messageLog = this.messages.asObservable()
      .pipe(scan((current, change) => {

        return [...current, `RESPONSE: ${change}`]
        }, []));

        console.log(this.messageLog);
      // this.messages.next(`CONNECT: ${this.address}`);
    }
```

It also shows that Subject.create(observer, observable) is deprecated what else i can use instead of this ? and also to what change should i do to show data on console

Comment: did you subscribe? 

Comment: sorry I am new to angular can you guide me or provide me with syntax of how to subscribe?

Comment: Can you please guide me  a bit in this issue @EricAska

Comment: observables are a way of handling asynchronous code. like here you created a observable (subject is one type of observable) and journey of data starts with observer by calling next(dataToSendThroughObservable) and receiving it by calling subject.subscribe((data)=>{ console.log('here is your data:', data); }).

Comment: And one of  specific thing about "Subject" is that when data comes and you haven't subscribed you miss the data. like a real life example missing a train if you are not in station.  add this `.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })` to after your `this._websocket.connect(...).pipe(map(...)...)` it comes after all the pipes and modifications you make to data before subscribing.

Comment: Thankyou so much for such a great explaination but implementing what you said gives me the error code `"Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<MessageEvent, any>'"`

and my code is


 `this.messages = <Subject<any>>this._websocket
        .connect(this.address).pipe(
        map((response: MessageEvent): any => {

          console.log("response1",response);


          return response.data;
        }).subscribe((data)=>{ console.log('here is your data:', data)}));`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-websocket-demo-testing?file=app%2Fshared%2Fservices%2Fwebsocket.service.ts check this out